# Cannot use $expand with BreezeJS and WebAPi OData

Tags: odata, breeze

i am working with the new VS2013 and created OData Controller with 2 models , Store and Products as client i have used KO,BreezeJS and DataJs
i saw that expand is not working, i have send this issue to microsoft poeple in codeplex site and they told me that all is ok with my code

```
 my.vm = {
        stores: ko.observableArray([]),
        load: function () {
            var serverAddress = "/odata";
            breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
            var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);


            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Store").expand("Products");
            manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
                var results = data.results;
                $.each(data.results, function (i, c) {
                    my.vm.stores.push(c);
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

adding the request/response

```
http://localhost:16894/odata/Store?$expand=Products

{
```

"odata.metadata":"/odata/$metadata#Store","value":[
    {
      "odata.type":"WebApplication1.Models.Store","odata.id":"/odata/Store(1)","Products@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"/odata/Store(1)/Products","Products":[
        {
          "odata.type":"WebApplication1.Models.Product","odata.id":/odata/Product(1)","ID":1,"Name":"1"
        },{
          "odata.type":"WebApplication1.Models.Product","odata.id":"/odata/Product(2)","ID":2,"Name":"2"
        }
      ],"ID":1,"Name":"1"
    },{
      "odata.type":"WebApplication1.Models.Store","odata.id":/odata/Store(2)","Products@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"/odata/Store(2)/Products","Products":[
        {
          "odata.type":"WebApplication1.Models.Product","odata.id":"/odata/Product(2)","ID":2,"Name":"1"
        },{
          "odata.type":"WebApplication1.Models.Product","odata.id":"/odata/Product(3)","ID":3,"Name":"2"
        }
      ],"ID":2,"Name":"1"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: only warning from q - [Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): 
[ReferenceError]

Comment: How are you constructing the OData controller, via a WCF DataService or with MS's OData model builder?

Comment: MS OData model builder

Comment: Please you something like Fiddler to provide the actual request that was sent to the server and a sample of the response that you received. That will make debugging this easier.

Comment: Unless you are using one of the MS OData model builder nightly builds, then this is unlikely to work.  The "released" MS OData ModelBuilder does not support the definition of foreign keys which Breeze needs.  Another poster pointed out that this has been fixed in one of the nightly builds, but we have not yet confirmed it.